# What's the difference between "hidden" and "output" in PyTorch LSTM?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tensor

I'm having trouble understanding the documentation for PyTorch's LSTM module (and also RNN and GRU, which are similar). Regarding the outputs, it says:

> Outputs: output, (h_n, c_n)
>
> - output (seq_len, batch, hidden_size * num_directions): tensor containing the output features (h_t) from the last layer of the RNN, for each t. If a torch.nn.utils.rnn.PackedSequence has been given as the input, the output will also be a packed sequence.
> - h_n (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size): tensor containing the hidden state for t=seq_len
> - c_n (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size): tensor containing the cell state for t=seq_len

It seems that the variables `output` and `h_n` both give the values of the hidden state. Does `h_n` just redundantly provide the last time step that's already included in `output`, or is there something more to it than that?

Answer (score 245, accepted):

I made a diagram. The names follow the [PyTorch docs](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.LSTM), although I renamed `num_layers` to `w`.

`output` comprises all the hidden states in the last layer ("last" depth-wise, not time-wise). `(h_n, c_n)` comprises the hidden states after the last timestep, *t* = *n*, so you could potentially feed them into another LSTM.

[image: LSTM diagram]

The batch dimension is not included.

Comment: Great, thanks, that makes a lot of sense and is really helpful. So that means, for example, that there is no way to get the hidden values for all layers at a time step other than the last one?

Comment: Right, unless you have individual LSTMs with `num_layers = 1` that take the previous net's output as input.

Comment: @nnnmmm So, each (blue) box is an LSTM/RNN/GRU unit, right? And `h_i` and `c_i` are the *hidden and cell states* resp and `w` is the depth of our network, right?

Comment: @kmario23: yes, each blue box is an LSTM unit. As I understand, vanilla RNN and GRU don't have cell states, just hidden states, so they would look a little different. You're right about `h_i`, `c_i` and `w`.

Comment: there are two units labeled `h_1^(1)`, the right one probably should have `h_2^(1)`

Comment: @nnnmmm: What did you use to make the diagram, may I ask?

Comment: It was draw.io, but I'm not sure if it's the best tool for the job.

Comment: @nnnmmm, is the number of h (depth-wise) is the number of stacked lstm cell?

Comment: It would be much appreciated if you add a similar graph for bidirectional LSTM :).

Comment: This is way clearer than Pytorch's official doc. They should include this pic. So many thanks for this. Amazing. Now I understand exactly what the output means.

Comment: So for depth 1 LSTM, the following statement from the question will be correct:

*Does h_n just redundantly provide the last time step that's already included in output*

Comment: The documentation mentions o_t as output gate, and then says here that this output refers to h_t for each time step. This is causing a lot of confusion.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say thank you, but I don't care. This diagram is great. I've been blindly coding LSTMs for a while and this really clarified what's going on under the hood in a way the docs never did.

Comment: how does $h_1^1$ combine with $h_2^0$?

Answer (score 6):

I just verified some of this using code, and its indeed correct that if it's a depth 1 LSTM, then *h_n* is the same as the last value of the "output". (this will not be true for > 1 depth LSTM though as explained above by @nnnmmm)

So, basically the "output" we get after applying LSTM is not the same as *o_t* as defined in the documentation, rather it is *h_t*.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

torch.manual_seed(0)
model = nn.LSTM( input_size = 1, hidden_size = 50, num_layers  = 1 )
x = torch.rand( 50, 1, 1)
output, (hn, cn) = model(x)
```

Now one can check that `output[-1]` and `hn` both have the same value as follows

```
tensor([[ 0.1140, -0.0600, -0.0540,  0.1492, -0.0339, -0.0150, -0.0486,  0.0188,
          0.0504,  0.0595, -0.0176, -0.0035,  0.0384, -0.0274,  0.1076,  0.0843,
         -0.0443,  0.0218, -0.0093,  0.0002,  0.1335,  0.0926,  0.0101, -0.1300,
         -0.1141,  0.0072, -0.0142,  0.0018,  0.0071,  0.0247,  0.0262,  0.0109,
          0.0374,  0.0366,  0.0017,  0.0466,  0.0063,  0.0295,  0.0536,  0.0339,
          0.0528, -0.0305,  0.0243, -0.0324,  0.0045, -0.1108, -0.0041, -0.1043,
         -0.0141, -0.1222]], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)
```

Answer (score 6):

In Pytorch, the output parameter gives the output of each individual LSTM cell in the last layer of the LSTM stack, while hidden state and cell state give the output of each hidden cell and cell state in the LSTM stack in every layer.

```
import torch.nn as nn
torch.manual_seed(1)
inputs = [torch.randn(1, 3) for _ in range(5)] # indicates that there are 5 sequences to be given as inputs and (1,3) indicates that there is 1 layer with 3 cells
hidden = (torch.randn(1, 1, 3),
          torch.randn(1, 1, 3)) #initializing h and c values to be of dimensions (1, 1, 3) which indicates there is (1 * 1) - num_layers * num_directions, with batch size of 1 and projection size of 3. 
                                #Since there is only 1 batch in input, h and c can also have only one batch of data for initialization and the number of cells in both input and output should also match.
 
lstm = nn.LSTM(3, 3) #implying both input and output are 3 dimensional data
for i in inputs:
    out, hidden = lstm(i.view(1, 1, -1), hidden)
    print('out:', out)
    print('hidden:', hidden)
```

Output

```
out: tensor([[[-0.1124, -0.0653,  0.2808]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[-0.1124, -0.0653,  0.2808]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[-0.2883, -0.2846,  2.0720]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
out: tensor([[[ 0.1675, -0.0376,  0.4402]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[ 0.1675, -0.0376,  0.4402]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[ 0.4394, -0.1226,  1.5611]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
out: tensor([[[0.3699, 0.0150, 0.1429]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[0.3699, 0.0150, 0.1429]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[0.8432, 0.0618, 0.9413]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
out: tensor([[[0.1795, 0.0296, 0.2957]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[0.1795, 0.0296, 0.2957]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[0.4541, 0.1121, 0.9320]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
out: tensor([[[0.1365, 0.0596, 0.3931]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[0.1365, 0.0596, 0.3931]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[0.3430, 0.1948, 1.0255]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
```

Multi-Layered LSTM

```
import torch.nn as nn
torch.manual_seed(1)
num_layers = 2
inputs = [torch.randn(1, 3) for _ in range(5)] 
hidden = (torch.randn(2, 1, 3),
          torch.randn(2, 1, 3))
lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=3, hidden_size=3, num_layers=2)
for i in inputs:
    # Step through the sequence one element at a time.
    # after each step, hidden contains the hidden state.
    out, hidden = lstm(i.view(1, 1, -1), hidden)
    print('out:', out)
    print('hidden:', hidden)
```

Output

```
out: tensor([[[-0.0819,  0.1214, -0.2586]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[-0.2625,  0.4415, -0.4917]],

        [[-0.0819,  0.1214, -0.2586]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[-2.5740,  0.7832, -0.9211]],

        [[-0.2803,  0.5175, -0.5330]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
out: tensor([[[-0.1298,  0.2797, -0.0882]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[-0.3818,  0.3306, -0.3020]],

        [[-0.1298,  0.2797, -0.0882]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[-2.3980,  0.6347, -0.6592]],

        [[-0.3643,  0.9301, -0.1326]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
out: tensor([[[-0.1630,  0.3187,  0.0728]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[-0.5612,  0.3134, -0.0782]],

        [[-0.1630,  0.3187,  0.0728]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[-1.7555,  0.6882, -0.3575]],

        [[-0.4571,  1.2094,  0.1061]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
out: tensor([[[-0.1723,  0.3274,  0.1546]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[-0.5112,  0.1597, -0.0901]],

        [[-0.1723,  0.3274,  0.1546]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[-1.4417,  0.5892, -0.2489]],

        [[-0.4940,  1.3620,  0.2255]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
out: tensor([[[-0.1847,  0.2968,  0.1333]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[-0.3256,  0.3217, -0.1899]],

        [[-0.1847,  0.2968,  0.1333]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[-1.7925,  0.6096, -0.4432]],

        [[-0.5147,  1.4031,  0.2014]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
```

Bi-Directional Multi-Layered LSTM

```
import torch.nn as nn
torch.manual_seed(1)
num_layers = 2
is_bidirectional = True
inputs = [torch.randn(1, 3) for _ in range(5)] 
hidden = (torch.randn(4, 1, 3),
          torch.randn(4, 1, 3)) #4 -> (2 * 2) -> num_layers * num_directions
lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=3, hidden_size=3, num_layers=2, bidirectional=is_bidirectional)

for i in inputs:
    # Step through the sequence one element at a time.
    # after each step, hidden contains the hidden state.
    out, hidden = lstm(i.view(1, 1, -1), hidden)
    print('out:', out)
    print('hidden:', hidden)
    # output dim -> (seq_len, batch, num_directions * hidden_size) -> (5, 1, 2*3)
    # hidden dim -> (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size) -> (2 * 2, 1, 3)
    # cell state dim -> (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size) -> (2 * 2, 1, 3)
```

Output

```
out: tensor([[[-0.4620,  0.1115, -0.1087,  0.1646,  0.0173, -0.2196]]],
       grad_fn=<CatBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[ 0.5187,  0.2656, -0.2543]],

        [[ 0.4175,  0.0539,  0.0633]],

        [[-0.4620,  0.1115, -0.1087]],

        [[ 0.1646,  0.0173, -0.2196]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[ 1.1546,  0.4012, -0.4119]],

        [[ 0.7999,  0.2632,  0.2587]],

        [[-1.4196,  0.2075, -0.3148]],

        [[ 0.6605,  0.0243, -0.5783]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
out: tensor([[[-0.1860,  0.1359, -0.2719,  0.0815,  0.0061, -0.0980]]],
       grad_fn=<CatBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[ 0.2945,  0.0842, -0.1580]],

        [[ 0.2766, -0.1873,  0.2416]],

        [[-0.1860,  0.1359, -0.2719]],

        [[ 0.0815,  0.0061, -0.0980]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[ 0.5453,  0.1281, -0.2497]],

        [[ 0.9706, -0.3592,  0.4834]],

        [[-0.3706,  0.2681, -0.6189]],

        [[ 0.2029,  0.0121, -0.3028]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
out: tensor([[[ 0.1095,  0.1520, -0.3238,  0.0283,  0.0387, -0.0820]]],
       grad_fn=<CatBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[ 0.1427,  0.0859, -0.2926]],

        [[ 0.1536, -0.2343,  0.0727]],

        [[ 0.1095,  0.1520, -0.3238]],

        [[ 0.0283,  0.0387, -0.0820]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[ 0.2386,  0.1646, -0.4102]],

        [[ 0.2636, -0.4828,  0.1889]],

        [[ 0.1967,  0.2848, -0.7155]],

        [[ 0.0735,  0.0702, -0.2859]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
out: tensor([[[ 0.2346,  0.1576, -0.4006, -0.0053,  0.0256, -0.0653]]],
       grad_fn=<CatBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[ 0.1706,  0.0147, -0.0341]],

        [[ 0.1835, -0.3951,  0.2506]],

        [[ 0.2346,  0.1576, -0.4006]],

        [[-0.0053,  0.0256, -0.0653]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[ 0.3422,  0.0269, -0.0475]],

        [[ 0.4235, -0.9144,  0.5655]],

        [[ 0.4589,  0.2807, -0.8332]],

        [[-0.0133,  0.0507, -0.1996]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
out: tensor([[[ 0.2774,  0.1639, -0.4460, -0.0228,  0.0086, -0.0369]]],
       grad_fn=<CatBackward>)
hidden: (tensor([[[ 0.2147, -0.0191,  0.0677]],

        [[ 0.2516, -0.4591,  0.3327]],

        [[ 0.2774,  0.1639, -0.4460]],

        [[-0.0228,  0.0086, -0.0369]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>), tensor([[[ 0.4414, -0.0299,  0.0889]],

        [[ 0.6360, -1.2360,  0.7229]],

        [[ 0.5692,  0.2843, -0.9375]],

        [[-0.0569,  0.0177, -0.1039]]], grad_fn=<StackBackward>))
```

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on a model you use and how you will interpret the model. Output may be:

- a single LSTM cell hidden state
- several LSTM cell hidden states
- all the hidden states outputs

Output, is almost never interpreted directly. If the input is encoded there should be a softmax layer to decode the results.

Note: In language modeling hidden states are used to define the probability of the next word, p(w<sub>t+1</sub>|w<sub>1</sub>,...,w<sub>t</sub>) =softmax(Wh<sub>t</sub>+b).

Answer (score 3):

The output state is the tensor of all the hidden state from each time step in the RNN(LSTM), and the hidden state returned by the RNN(LSTM) is the last hidden state from the last time step from the input sequence. You could check this by collecting all of the hidden states from each step and comparing that to the output state,(provided you are not using pack_padded_sequence).