# Is hidden and output the same for a GRU unit in Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I do understand conceptually what an LSTM or GRU should (thanks to this question [What's the difference between "hidden" and "output" in PyTorch LSTM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302810/whats-the-difference-between-hidden-and-output-in-pytorch-lstm)) BUT when I inspect the output of the GRU `h_n` and `output` are NOT the same while they should be...

```
(Pdb) rnn_output
tensor([[[ 0.2663,  0.3429, -0.0415,  ...,  0.1275,  0.0719,  0.1011],
         [-0.1272,  0.3096, -0.0403,  ...,  0.0589, -0.0556, -0.3039],
         [ 0.1064,  0.2810, -0.1858,  ...,  0.3308,  0.1150, -0.3348],
         ...,
         [-0.0929,  0.2826, -0.0554,  ...,  0.0176, -0.1552, -0.0427],
         [-0.0849,  0.3395, -0.0477,  ...,  0.0172, -0.1429,  0.0153],
         [-0.0212,  0.1257, -0.2670,  ..., -0.0432,  0.2122, -0.1797]]],
       grad_fn=<StackBackward>)
(Pdb) hidden
tensor([[[ 0.1700,  0.2388, -0.4159,  ..., -0.1949,  0.0692, -0.0630],
         [ 0.1304,  0.0426, -0.2874,  ...,  0.0882,  0.1394, -0.1899],
         [-0.0071,  0.1512, -0.1558,  ..., -0.1578,  0.1990, -0.2468],
         ...,
         [ 0.0856,  0.0962, -0.0985,  ...,  0.0081,  0.0906, -0.1234],
         [ 0.1773,  0.2808, -0.0300,  ..., -0.0415, -0.0650, -0.0010],
         [ 0.2207,  0.3573, -0.2493,  ..., -0.2371,  0.1349, -0.2982]],

        [[ 0.2663,  0.3429, -0.0415,  ...,  0.1275,  0.0719,  0.1011],
         [-0.1272,  0.3096, -0.0403,  ...,  0.0589, -0.0556, -0.3039],
         [ 0.1064,  0.2810, -0.1858,  ...,  0.3308,  0.1150, -0.3348],
         ...,
         [-0.0929,  0.2826, -0.0554,  ...,  0.0176, -0.1552, -0.0427],
         [-0.0849,  0.3395, -0.0477,  ...,  0.0172, -0.1429,  0.0153],
         [-0.0212,  0.1257, -0.2670,  ..., -0.0432,  0.2122, -0.1797]]],
       grad_fn=<StackBackward>)
```

they are some transpose of each other...why?

Answer (score 4):

They are not *really* the same. Consider that we have the following **Unidirectional** GRU model:

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch

gru = nn.GRU(input_size = 8, hidden_size = 50, num_layers = 3, batch_first = True)
```

*Please make sure you observe the input shape carefully.*

```
inp = torch.randn(1024, 112, 8)
out, hn = gru(inp)
```

Definitely,

```
torch.equal(out, hn)
False
```

One of the most efficient ways that helped me to understand the output vs. hidden states was to view the `hn` as `hn.view(num_layers, num_directions, batch, hidden_size)` *where `num_directions = 2` for bidirectional recurrent networks (and 1 other wise, i.e., our case)*. Thus,

```
hn_conceptual_view = hn.view(3, 1, 1024, 50)
```

As the doc states (Note the *italics* and **bolds**):

> h_n of shape (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size): **tensor containing the hidden state for t = seq_len** (i.e., for the last timestep)

In our case, this contains the hidden vector for the timestep `t = 112`, where the:

> output of shape (seq_len, batch, num_directions * hidden_size): *tensor containing the output features h_t from the **last layer** of the GRU, **for each t**.* If a torch.nn.utils.rnn.PackedSequence has been given as the input, the output will also be a packed sequence. For the unpacked case, the directions can be separated using output.view(seq_len, batch, num_directions, hidden_size), with forward and backward being direction 0 and 1 respectively.

So, consequently, one can do:

```
torch.equal(out[:, -1], hn_conceptual_view[-1, 0, :, :])
True
```

*Explanation*: I compare the last sequence from all batches in `out[:, -1]` to the last layer hidden vectors from `hn[-1, 0, :, :]`

---

For **Bidirectional** GRU (requires reading the unidirectional first):

```
gru = nn.GRU(input_size = 8, hidden_size = 50, num_layers = 3, batch_first = True bidirectional = True)
inp = torch.randn(1024, 112, 8)
out, hn = gru(inp)
```

View is changed to (since we have two directions):

```
hn_conceptual_view = hn.view(3, 2, 1024, 50)
```

If you try the exact code:

```
torch.equal(out[:, -1], hn_conceptual_view[-1, 0, :, :])
False
```

*Explanation*: This is because we are even comparing wrong shapes;

```
out[:, 0].shape
torch.Size([1024, 100])
hn_conceptual_view[-1, 0, :, :].shape
torch.Size([1024, 50])
```

Remember that for bidirectional networks, hidden states get concatenated at each time step where the first `hidden_state` size (i.e., `out[:, 0,` **`:50`**`]`) are the the hidden states for the forward network, and the other `hidden_state` size are for the backward (i.e., `out[:, 0,` **`50:`**`]`). The correct comparison for the **forward network** is then:

```
torch.equal(out[:, -1, :50], hn_conceptual_view[-1, 0, :, :])
True
```

If you want the hidden states for the **backward network**, and [since a backward network processes the sequence from time step `n ... 1`](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4b80/89bc9b49f84de43acc2eb8900035f7d492b2.pdf#page=3). You compare the first timestep of the sequence **but the last `hidden_state` size** and changing the `hn_conceptual_view` direction to `1`:

```
torch.equal(out[:, -1, :50], hn_conceptual_view[-1, 1, :, :])
True
```

---

In a nutshell, generally speaking:

**Unidirectional**:

```
rnn_module = nn.RECURRENT_MODULE(num_layers = X, hidden_state = H, batch_first = True)
inp = torch.rand(B, S, E)
output, hn = rnn_module(inp)
hn_conceptual_view = hn.view(X, 1, B, H)
```

Where `RECURRENT_MODULE` is either GRU or LSTM (at the time of writing this post), `B` is the batch size, `S` sequence length, and `E` embedding size.

```
torch.equal(output[:, S, :], hn_conceptual_view[-1, 0, :, :])
True
```

Again we used `S` since the `rnn_module` is forward (i.e., unidirectional) and the last timestep is stored at the sequence length `S`.

**Bidirectional**:

```
rnn_module = nn.RECURRENT_MODULE(num_layers = X, hidden_state = H, batch_first = True, bidirectional = True)
inp = torch.rand(B, S, E)
output, hn = rnn_module(inp)
hn_conceptual_view = hn.view(X, 2, B, H)
```

Comparison

```
torch.equal(output[:, S, :H], hn_conceptual_view[-1, 0, :, :])
True
```

Above is the forward network comparison, we used `:H` because the forward stores its hidden vector in the first `H` elements for each timestep.

For the backward network:

```
torch.equal(output[:, 0, H:], hn_conceptual_view[-1, 1, :, :])
True
```

We changed the direction in `hn_conceptual_view` to `1` to get hidden vectors for the backward network.

---

For all examples we used `hn_conceptual_view[-1, ...]` because we are only interested in the last layer.

Answer (score 3):

There are three things you have to remember to make sense of this in PyTorch.
This answer is written on the assumption that you are using something like torch.nn.GRU or the like, and that if you are making a multi-layer RNN with it, *that you are using the `num_layers` argument to do so* (rather than building one from scratch out of individual layers yourself.)

1. The `output` will give you the hidden layer outputs of the network for each time-step, *but only for the final layer*. This is useful in many applications, particularly encoder-decoders using attention.  (These architectures build up a 'context' layer from all the hidden outputs, and it is extremely useful to have them sitting around as a self-contained unit.)
2. The `h_n` will give you the hidden layer outputs for the last time-step only, but for all the layers.  Therefore, if and only if you have a single layer architecture, `h_n` is a strict subset of `output`.  Otherwise, `output` and `h_n` intersect, but are not strict subsets of one another.  (You will often want these, in an encoder-decoder model, from the encoder in order to jumpstart the decoder.)
3. If you are using a bidirectional output and you want to actually verify that part of `h_n` is contained in `output` (and vice-versa) you need to understand what PyTorch does behind the scenes in the organization of the inputs and outputs.  Specifically, it concatenates a time-reversed input with the time-forward input and runs them together.  This is literal.  This means that the 'forward' output at time T is in the final position of the `output` tensor sitting right next to the 'reverse' output at time 0; if you're looking for the 'reverse' output at time T, it is in the first position.

The third point in particular drove me absolute bonkers for about three hours the first time I was playing RNNs and GRUs.  In fairness, it is also why `h_n` is provided as an output, so once you figure it out, you don't have to worry about it any more, you just get the right stuff from the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Is Not the transpose , 
you can get  rnn_output = hidden[-1] when the layer of lstm is 1

hidden is a output of every cell every layer, it's shound be a 2D array for a specifc input time step , but lstm return all the time step , so the output of a layer should be hidden[-1]

and this situation discussed when batch is 1 , or the dimention of output and hidden need to add one