# LSTM layer output size vs. hidden state size in KERAS

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am in trouble with understanding the concept of LSTM and using it on Keras. When considering a LSTM layer, there should be two values for output size and the hidden state size.

```
1. hidden state size : how many features are passed across the time steps of a samples when training the model
2. output size       : how many outputs should be returned by particular LSTM layer
```

But in keras.layers.LSTM, there is only one parameter and it is used to control the output size of the layer.

PROBLEM:

```
Therefore how hidden state size of the LSTM layer can be changed?
```

If I am misunderstood, corrections are really appreciated.

Comment: Similar questions: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/15621/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-size-of-the-hidden-layer-and-the-size-of-th and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468927/when-computing-parameters-why-is-dimensions-of-hidden-output-state-of-an-lstm-c

Answer (score 2):

Referring to this [article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/lstms-explained-a-complete-technically-accurate-conceptual-guide-with-keras-2a650327e8f2):

As far as I understand, the hidden state size of an LSTM is called `units` in keras. The size of the output then depends on how many time steps there are in the input data and what the dimension of the hidden state (`units`) is. This could also become clearer when looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302810/whats-the-difference-between-hidden-and-output-in-pytorch-lstm).

Answer (score -2):

You are getting confused between the difference in hidden units and output units in LSTM. Please refer to the below link for better clarity:

https://jasdeep06.github.io/posts/Understanding-LSTM-in-Tensorflow-MNIST/

Basically what you provide in num_units is the size of LSTM hidden unit only. This is very clear from this article.