# Understanding the Distinction Between LSTM Output and Hidden State Output

Tags: pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently in the process of developing a wake word model for my AI Assistant, and I'm facing a dilemma regarding which output I should feed into my Linear Layer. Could someone clarify the difference between the two available outputs, and provide insight into why one should consider a specific recommendation for making the choice?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between "hidden" and "output" in PyTorch LSTM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302810/whats-the-difference-between-hidden-and-output-in-pytorch-lstm)

Answer (score 0):

You should give the output to the linear layer instead of hidden state output.
Like this (time series prediction):

```py
def forward(self, input_seq):
    h_0 = torch.randn(self.num_directions * self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
    c_0 = torch.randn(self.num_directions * self.num_layers, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size).to(device)
    seq_len = input_seq.shape[1]
    input_seq = input_seq.view(self.batch_size, seq_len, 1)
    output, _ = self.lstm(input_seq, (h_0, c_0))
    output = output.contiguous().view(self.batch_size * seq_len, self.hidden_size)
    pred = self.linear(output)
    pred = pred.view(self.batch_size, seq_len, -1)
    pred = pred[:, -1, :]
    return pred
```

The output contains the hidden state output at all time steps in the last layer, and the hidden state output is only the hidden states at the last time step.

Comment: What if the word is too small in that audio? shoudn't i just collect the couple timesteps of hidden state output and predict with that?

Comment: In language modeling you need the hidden state output at all time steps.